# How do I send a variable back to the main program from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with my code

I want my code to return the name of a file created by a user command to my main program but I don't know how, I've tried return filename but that did not work, here is the code:

```
#File Creator 
def Create(filename):
    UserFile = open(str(filename), "wt")
    file = (str(filename))
    return file

#Main program
Create(input("filename: "))
print(file)
```

I'm using python 3.3, how do I set file as a variable that can be used from anywhere in the code?

I was thinking about adding `file = Create(input("filename: "))` but I'm not sure if there is another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `global`:

```
def Create(filename):
    global file
    UserFile = open(str(filename), "wt")
    file = (str(filename))
    #return file  -- I commented this since there is no real reason to return now with a global
```

`file` will now be in the global scope.

Personally though I think your method of `file = Create(input("filename: "))` is the best.  Using globals like that is frowned upon by many and can quite often be avoided.

Comment: Thank you, I looked up global but it did not work when I tried, I see why now, The other method would not work as well for me because i need to call it in a way that can change "file" whenever the command is called

Comment: Note that it is good practice to use `global` at the very beginning of the function, not just prior to the code that actually uses the variable.

Answer (score 3):

How come returning the file didn't work? although you have several mistakes in the code. Try this, it should do the trick:

```
# File Creator 
def create(filename):
    userFile = open(filename, "rw")
    return userFile # this is a file object

# Main program
theFile = create(input("filename: "))
print(str(theFile)) # string representation of the file object
```

By all means, **avoid using global variables** if there's no real need for them - global variables are a *very bad* programming practice. In this simple case it suffices to pass values as parameters and/or return values, in a well-structured program that should be enough for your needs.